# Nonlinear acoustic processes in air - how to quantitatively estimate power in four-wave mixing?

Tags: acoustics, non-linear-systems

I'd like to understand if non-linear mixing of human speech with a high-power ultrasonic "carrier" in air could produce sidebands with more power than the original speech.

30 kHz to 300 kHz has a wavelength range from about 10 down to 1 millimeter in air. This is still much longer than the mean free path, but air is not an extremely high-fidelity medium at high sound pressure levels, especially when the pressure gets anywhere near comparable to the static pressure.

The Wikipedia article [Nonlinear acoustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-wave_mixing) gives several mathematical model for the propagation of a single wave taking into account the nonlinear response of air to sound with a "high amplitude to wavelength ratio", but what I'm trying to understand is how to estimate the power in the sideband produced in the acoustic analog of *[four-wave mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-wave_mixing)*.

If someone could even just help guide me through the excellent presentation [Introductory Lecture on Nonlinear Acoustics](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/~vtournat/wa_files/NLALectureVT.pdf) by Vincent Tournat at CNRS so that I can calculate the sideband power, that would be great!

[image]

[image]